# does spring data mongo suporting cache and cluster

Tags: mongodb, caching, cluster-computing, spring-data

I have a general question.  Does spring data for Mongo support clustering and caching?  If so, can you point me to the right direction.

Comment: Welcome to the party! No need to say "thanks" or add a signature here. It's considered noisy, and does not add anything to the question itself. Plus, StackOverflow is not the website to go to if you want external resources (we want all the answers on SO itself!). Please edit your question accordingly, and have fun sharing knowledge.